# Migration to Version 2.0 of LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Recently I created an application for the LinkedIn API (Status is Development). 
I managed to do requests to the old v1 version of the API, for example 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~' and '/v1/people/~/shares'. But when I try to use the new version, v2, of the API I encounter some problems.

**Problem 1**: When I try to request 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me' I get the following error:

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
"status": 403
}
```

From what I understand to fix this problem I should use the 'r_liteprofile' scope when requesting a access token. But this leads to my next problem.

**Problem 2**: When I request the oauth endpoint (`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={state}&scope=r_liteprofile`) I get the following error:

```
error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope &quot;r_liteprofile&quot; is not authorized for your application
```

So I figured I need to select these scopes in the Application settings. But that leads to my third and final problem.

**Problem 3**: I am unable to select the required application permissions at 'https://www.linkedin.com/developer' for my application.
[My Default Application Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKHXe.png)

How do I manage to use the new (v2) API version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moving first you check :
you have to check Linkedin - Myapp - Default Application Permissions

You have r_liteprofile permission or not ( for calling this  'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me)

in V2 you can use : r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id r_emailaddress for getting emailAddress

Check this :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: I tried to use the r_liteprofile but that did not work as explained in Problem 2 and Problem 3 of my post.

Comment: if you read my link then every thing is written there Check this like in that link : All developer applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Portal after January 14, 2019 have access to the LinkedIn v2 API by default. Means if you have created old then no problem : if you will create now then you will not get new V2 permission : if you create on 14th or after that then you will get by default r_liteprofile permission :  let me ask if still not clear

Comment: Alright, thanks! So I will have to create another application after January 14, 2019 if I want access to v2 API?
Do you know what will happen if I apply for the 'LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program' now with my current application? Will I get access to v2?

Comment: Yes, according to his document if you create new after 14th then by default they will provide V2 API access, I created recently new app for testing r_liteprofile  was not there in new created app, but my Old app which we are using for last 5-6 years that is there by default , yes you can apply for partnership program if they will approved then you can use/access V2 API and many other api also .. thanks